# Android Emulator resets at every boot

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I downloaded the Android SDK command line tools for Linux, downloaded the required all the components needed to create an AVD and created an android Emulator using the following command:

`./avdmanager create avd -n AVD -k "system-images;android-33;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"`.

However, every time I boot the Emulator it starts as it did at a fresh install.
I'm not sure about how to configure it so that the data is saved.

I'm trying to avoid using Android Studio, since I don't do Android development anymore.

This is the content of my `config.ini` file:

```
PlayStore.enabled=yes
abi.type=x86_64
android.avd.home=/home/adbullah/.android/avd/AVD.d/
avd.id=12
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
avd.name=AVD
disk.cachePartition=yes
disk.cachePartition.path=yes
disk.cachePartition.size=66MB
disk.dataPartition.size=16000
disk.systemPartition.size=0
disk.vendorPartition.size=0
fastboot.forceColdBoot=yes
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.arc=no
hw.arc.autologin=no
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.audioOutput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=virtualscene
hw.camera.front=emulated
hw.cpu.arch=x86_64
hw.cpu.ncore=2
hw.dPad=yes
hw.device.name=AVD
hw.display1.density=0
hw.display1.flag=0
hw.display1.height=0
hw.display1.width=0
hw.display1.xOffset=-1
hw.display1.yOffset=-1
hw.display2.density=0
hw.display2.flag=0
hw.display2.height=0
hw.display2.width=0
hw.display2.xOffset=-1
hw.display2.yOffset=-1
hw.display3.density=0
hw.display3.flag=0
hw.display3.height=0
hw.display3.width=0
hw.display3.xOffset=-1
hw.display3.yOffset=-1
hw.displayRegion.0.1.height=0
hw.displayRegion.0.1.width=0
hw.displayRegion.0.1.xOffset=-1
hw.displayRegion.0.1.yOffset=-1
hw.displayRegion.0.2.height=0
hw.displayRegion.0.2.width=0
hw.displayRegion.0.2.xOffset=-1
hw.displayRegion.0.2.yOffset=-1
hw.displayRegion.0.3.height=0
hw.displayRegion.0.3.width=0
hw.displayRegion.0.3.xOffset=-1
hw.displayRegion.0.3.yOffset=-1
hw.gltransport=pipe
hw.gltransport.asg.dataRingSize=32768
hw.gltransport.asg.writeBufferSize=1048576
hw.gltransport.asg.writeStepSize=4096
hw.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto
hw.gsmModem=yes
hw.gyroscope=yes
hw.initialOrientation=portrait
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.keyboard.charmap=qwerty2
hw.keyboard.lid=yes
hw.lcd.backlight=yes
hw.lcd.density=160
hw.lcd.depth=16
hw.lcd.height=1280
hw.lcd.vsync=60
hw.lcd.width=720
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.multi_display_window=no
hw.ramSize=2048
hw.rotaryInput=no
hw.screen=multi-touch
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensor.hinge=no
hw.sensor.hinge.count=0
hw.sensor.hinge.fold_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture=1
hw.sensor.hinge.sub_type=0
hw.sensor.hinge.type=0
hw.sensor.roll=no
hw.sensor.roll.count=0
hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture=6
hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.2_at_posture=6
hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.3_at_posture=6
hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated=yes
hw.sensors.heart_rate=no
hw.sensors.humidity=yes
hw.sensors.light=yes
hw.sensors.magnetic_field=yes
hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.pressure=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.sensors.rgbclight=no
hw.sensors.temperature=yes
hw.sensors.wrist_tilt=no
hw.trackBall=yes
hw.useext4=yes
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-33/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
kernel.newDeviceNaming=autodetect
kernel.supportsYaffs2=autodetect
tag.display=Google Play
tag.id=google_apis_playstore
test.delayAdbTillBootComplete=0
test.monitorAdb=0
test.quitAfterBootTimeOut=-1
vm.heapSize=112M
```

I would really appreciate any help, thanks a lot.